# Give "Backup and Sync from Google" access only to "~/Google Drive" directory (on Big Sur)

Tags: big-sur, google-apps

My Google Drive (aka Backup and Sync from Google) is `/Users/marcin/Google Drive`.  I upgraded to Big Sur and Google Drive stopped synchronizing due to access restrictions.  The only options I can find to get Google Drive working are:

1. Give Google Drive access to my entire drive - definitely do not want to do that
2. Move the directory to `/Users/marcin/Documents/Google Drive` and give it access to my entire **Documents** folder - do not want to do that either.

**The question:** Is there a way to keep the local repository in `/Users/marcin/Google Drive` and give Google Drive access just to this directory?

**Alternative:** Is there a locating I could place `Google Drive` directory such that I could restrict access to just that directory?